# Android Studio - "Installing APK" loading bar never changes

Tags: android, installation, adb, device

[logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5odo.jpg)

I can't use an emulator because it tells me computer can't handle it. However I have an android device (Huawei P8 Lite) which worked just fine when I first installed Android Studio. When I try to run the app on my phone, it recognizes the phone, I select it and according to the phone the app is installed and everything is fine, but on Android Studio the "Installing APK" loading bar never ever finishes it doesn't even move, so I assume there must be something wrong, especially because some errors show on the logcat. Errors like:

> 11-23 21:43:28.482 17187-17187/com.product.notebook E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc

PS: I tried to use the code adb install name.apk but it didn't work

Comment: You say you see errors in your logcat. Can you add the relevant part of the logcat output to your post? Without those, there's nothing we can do.

Comment: Of course. I should add that the project that I have, I haven't even done any changes. I just created it and tried to run it. I put the logcat image in the original post. I hope that's how I was supposed to do it.